# Query performance degrades when changing sort order from ascending to descending in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a sample `Test` collection with almost 1 million data with sample like:

```
{
    data:[
        {
           property: 'firstName',
           value: 'Robins' 
        },
        {
           property: 'position',
           value: 6000
        }
    ],
    dataObj:{
        firstName: 'Robins',
        position: 6000
    }
}

//indexes
1. db.Test.createIndex({ "data.property": 1, "data.value":1 })
2. db.Test.createIndex({ "dataObj.position": 1 })
```

**I am getting different performance on two different query here:**

> QUERY 1

Query with position <= 6000 and Sort in `ascending` order of position

```
db.Test.find({ 
   'data': {
      $elemMatch: { property: 'position', value: { $lte: 60000 } }
   }  
 }).limit(10).sort({ 'dataObj.position': 1 }).explain("executionStats");
```

> QUERY 2

Query with position <= 6000 and Sort in `descending` order of position

```
db.Test.find({
 'data': {
   $elemMatch: { property: 'position', value: { $lte: 60000 } }
  }  
}).limit(10).sort({ 'dataObj.position': -1 }).explain("executionStats");
```

> Query 1 Execution Stats

```
{
   ...
   "executionStats" : {
       "executionSuccess" : true,
       "nReturned" : 10,
       "executionTimeMillis" : 2,
       "totalKeysExamined" : 30,
       "totalDocsExamined" : 30,
   }
   ...
}
```

> Query 2 Execution Stats

```
{
   ...
   "executionStats" : {
       "executionSuccess" : true,
       "nReturned" : 10,
       "executionTimeMillis" : 4323,
       "totalKeysExamined" : 167327,
       "totalDocsExamined" : 167327,
   }
   ...
}
```

**I am not able to figure out why there such much major difference in performace with just minor change in the query?**

Comment: You do not need to shout. If we were stupid, you would not ask us the first place, would you? ;) Aside from that: curious. My assumption would be that the first query has an index intersection while the second one has not. To verify this, please have a look into the explanation of each query and look out for `AND_SORTED` and/or `AND_HASH` sections and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51454958/edit) accordingly.